# Не сохраняется текст в файле после записи в него

Tags: c#, ооп, запись

Записываю в файл текст, но он не сохраняется, для теста, следующим шагом решил его прочитать и вдруг он выводится нужный текст, но после завершения программы файл не изменился, везде, где работал с файлом использовал "Using", поэтому все потоки закрыты!Также хотелось задать вопрос, почему редактирую текстовый файл в самой VS 2017, изменения не сохраняются(если просто открыть файл на рабочем столе). Ниже все скрины:
[image: Код записи и чтения]

Вот здесь начинается непонятное, в текстовом файле записано "test"(скрин ниже), после нажатия, запись и вывод из файла.Пробовал изменять свойства файла, но не помогло
[image: Форма и описание]

[image: Обозреватель решений]

[image: Свойства текстового файла]

[image: Сам текстовый файл]

[image: Расположение программы и текстового файла]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл "Obj.txt" из проекта находится не там, где Вы его открываете в коде для записи и чтения. Так как Вы не указываете путь к этому файлу, он записывается/читается в текущей директории запущенного процесса. Что отличается от местонахождения файла "Obj.txt", добавленного в проект.

Найдите скомпилированный exe файл Вашего проекта. Рядом с ним (или на уровень выше - не помню точно, какую папку VS устанавливает текущей, запуская программу) Вы обнаружите другой "Obj.txt" с ожидаемым содержимым.